# Bash readline blink-matching-paren not blinking matching parentheses

Tags: bash, readline

Bash `readline` has a setting called `blink-matching-paren` that is not working for me. If I type an open parenthesis on the command line, then some text, then a close parenthesis I don't get any blinking. Parentheses matching does work for me in `vim` and `emacs -nw`.

Here are the settings and versions, etc.:

```
$ bind -v | grep blink-matching-paren
set blink-matching-paren on
$ set -o | grep -E '\<(emacs|vi)\>'
emacs           on
vi              off
```

Various combinations of:

- Bash 4.0.33(1)-release
- Bash 4.1.9(2)-release
- Bash 3.2.51(24)-release
- mintty 0.9.2
- PuTTY 0.60 (with and without "Enable Blinking Text")
- xterm 243
- gnome-terminal 2.28.1
- TERM=xterm
- TERM=xterm-256color

What do I need to do to make parentheses matching work in Bash on the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting that in `.inputrc`, like:

```
$ cat ~/.inputrc
set blink-matching-paren on
```

Somehow this setting does not work for me when set interactively, but works fine that way.

Comment: That's just totally bizarre. It works. I added that and then did Ctrl-x Ctrl-r to re-read .inputrc and it worked. The weird thing is that `bind -v` showed that it was already set. By the way, try it with quotes from the command line: `bind 'set blink-matching-paren on'` - that works for me, too.